# How to avoid a `setState()` being called during a `build()` is in progress when this is called from an async callback in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, widget, setstate

Here is the context: My widget is in charge of playing a video, handling 2 mutually exclusive modes:

- Steaming mode: the video controller is passed to the widget as this enables for prebuffering;
- Download mode: a videoUrl could instead be provided and, in this case, the widget gets the responsibility to initiate the video.

The widget exposes a callback for the caller to be notified when the video is actually ready to start playing regardless of the mode.

The `StatefulWidget` runs from the `initState()` a `asyncInitState()` as follows:

```dart
  @override
  initState() {
    // == Copy the controller (or null)
    _videoController = widget.videoController;

    // == Decide download vs streaming mode
    _isDownloadMode = _videoController == null;
    _isStreamingMode = !_isDownloadMode;

    // == Start init video
    asyncInitState();
    super.initState();
  }
```

While the `asyncInitState()` prepares the video controller depending on the situation, as follows, eventually calling the callback:

```dart
void asyncInitState() {
    if (_isDownloadMode) {
      // == In download mode, we need to download the video when the URL is provided
      if (_videoController == null && widget.videoUrl != null) {
        _videoController = /*Cached*/ VideoPlayerController.network(
          widget.videoUrl!,
        );
      }
    }
    _videoController?.setLooping(widget.looping);

    _videoController?.addListener(() {
      if (!mounted) return;

      widget.listener?.call(isPlaying, position, duration);

      //setState(() {});
    });

    // == Only initialize once as the controller may have been passed to the widget
    final isInitialized = _videoController?.value.isInitialized ?? false;
    if (!isInitialized) {
      _videoController?.initialize().then((_) {
        widget.onStartPlaying?.call();
        _videoController?.play();
        if (!mounted) return;
        setState(
          () {},
        );
      }).catchError((err) {
        debugPrint('Error: $err'); // Prints 401.
      });
    } else {
      widget.onStartPlaying?.call();
      _videoController?.play();
    }
  }
```

As all of this take a few milliseconds (I mean it is not instantaneous), chances rise that the call back makes some `setState()` while the widget is already in the `build()` process, hence throwing an exception.

So the question is how would the caller knows the builder dis in progress?

But chances are the situation I face is a consequence of a flow in my design: so the real question might be how would you handle this situation?

Comment: "As all of this take a few milliseconds (I mean it is not instantaneous), chances rise that the call back makes some `setState()` while the widget is already in the `build()` process, hence throwing an exception." No.  The `build()` method itself is synchronous, and each Dart isolate is single-threaded.  The `build()` method therefore cannot be interrupted.  Unless your `build` method invokes `asyncInitState` (which *synchronously* calls `setState`), you should not encounter a "`setState` being called during a `build`" error.

Comment: Good point. But the exception is there, that's a fact. I think the video player might run in a different isolate or the underlying driver code. What do you think? Btw, the build does not call `asyncInitState()`.

Comment: That's not how that works.  Your Flutter UI code runs in a single isolate.  Your callback  that calls `setState` runs in the same isolate as the one that runs the `build()` method, so they cannot run in parallel.

Comment: ok thanks. I am going to better understand the situation I am facing then.

Comment: If you are encountering this error now, then that indicates that your `build` method is calling a function that *synchronously* calls `setState`.

Comment: Gotcha! "That's the *synchronously* calls `setState()`". By marking my callback async, everything works like a charm. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jamesdlin told me, the point is that my call back was **synchronously called** from the widget.

```
  onStartPlaying: () {
    playVideo();
  },
```

By making it asynchronous, the issue is solved:

```
  onStartPlaying: () async {
    // Wait for the next event loop to come to to make our set state asynchronous from the build
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)); 
    playVideo();
  },
```

Comment: I would not expect marking your callback with `async` to make a difference.  Adding that does not make the function asynchronous; executing the callback would still call `playVideo` immediately.

Comment: You mean I should call it like this right? `Future.delay(Duration(seconds:0).then(()=>playVideo());`. But that strange the exception does not longer pop. I am a bit puzzled.